# Sum of intervals in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck on this kata in CodeWars and I have tried for a long time, like for a week or so for one kata. If you want a description of my question, go [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b7ed099cdc285c300001cd).

This is my code, if you believe me, there are **lots of bugs** in it. Can someone please help me out?

```
public static int sumIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
    int sum = 0;
    int[] currentLargeInterval = {intervals[0][0], intervals[0][0]};
    ArrayList<int[]> addedIntervals = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<int[]> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
    addAll(arrays, intervals);
    ArrayList<int[]> removed = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (arrays.get(i - 1)[1] >= arrays.get(i)[0] && arrays.get(i - 1)[1] < arrays.get(i)[1]) {
                removed.add(arrays.get(i));
                currentLargeInterval[1] = arrays.get(i)[1];
            } else {
                addedIntervals.add(currentLargeInterval);
                currentLargeInterval = new int[]{arrays.get(i - 1)[0], arrays.get(i - 1)[0]};
            }
        }
    }
    addedIntervals.add(currentLargeInterval);
    arrays.removeAll(removed);
    arrays.addAll(addedIntervals);
    for (int[] a : arrays) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not homework, I just do Codewars for fun.

Comment: Plz Upvote me...??!!

Comment: The problem statement suggests converting two intervals that overlap into a single interval. For instance if you have intervals [1,4], [7,10], [3,5], then your code should convert them into the two intervals [1,5], [7,10]. After merging all the overlapping intervals, the problem simply involves looping through each merged interval and summing up the distance in each range.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this question needing the answer for some other problem rather than because they want to learn how to do it: Use Guava's RangeSet. For the OP: you're on the right track, but you're trying to do too much in one function. I suggest you write a helper function that takes a list of existing ranges that don't overlap plus a new range that might overlap the existing ranges, and returns a new list of nonoverlapping ranges that includes the new one. Then, in the main function, call that helper in a loop, adding each input range, one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating the solution in general (which makes bugs harder to find), it seems that all that is really required is that you do not add duplicates in a `Collection`, and output the size of the collection afterward.

I whipped up a quick version of this (I only tried it out against 2 of the tests).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] intervals = {{1,5},{10, 20},{1, 6},{16, 19},{5, 11}};
    System.out.println(sumIntervals(intervals));
}

public static int sumIntervals(int [][] intervals) {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int [] row : intervals) {
        for (int k = row[0]; k < row[1]; k++) {
            if (!values.contains(k)) {
                values.add(k);
            }
        }
    }
    return values.size();
}
```

**Output:**

> 19

This solution first iterates against the outer array to obtain each range, then uses those values to iterate between them and add each number into a `List` if the number is not already in the `List`, by utilizing `.contains()`.

Finally it returns the `size` of the `List` that contains each non-duplicated number.

Comment: Hello, I tested it and the runner says your code should be optimized.  Your code seems pretty slow due to the for loops in your algorithm.

Comment: @NoobyProgrammer  [2,3] and [4,5]  do not overlap.  Even according to the site you posted, the second value for each range is exclusive.  That's why [1,4] is a range of 3.  In other words, the length of a range for `[a,b] is b-a`.  If the site says otherwise for a particular test case, it is wrong.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I was supposed to test [2, 4], [3,5] for the answer to actually to be 3.

Comment: @Nexevis I think your code should be optimized a little.  Your code passes all of the tests but runs out of time and fails.

Comment: @NoobyProgrammer Well it depends what you are prioritizing, readability, or code that runs fast. When I initially wrote this I don't think you said there was a time constraint on how fast the code needs to run.  I went for easy to read code.

Comment: @Nexevis Can you please edit your own post and make it have a better time complexity? I suppose the answer won't be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I went and got this super fast answer using `Intstream`.

```
 public static int sumIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
        return intervals == null ? 0 : (int) Arrays.stream(intervals)
            .flatMapToInt(interval -> IntStream.range(interval[0], interval[1]))
            .distinct()
            .count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a slightly different solution using `BitSet`  The principle is simple.  Set the range of bits depicted by the specified ranges in the test suite.
Overlaps are handled by the fact the some bits will be set multiple times within an already established range.  The `cardinality` is the number of bits set which is also the sum of the ranges.

```java
        BitSet b = new BitSet();
        for (int[] arr : list) {
            b.set(arr[0],arr[1]);
        }
        sum = b.cardinality();
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, the code @Nexevis provided will work but it can be faster just by using a set instead of an ArrayList.

```
    public static int sumIntervals(int [][] intervals) {
       if(intervals == null || intervals.length == 0) {
         return 0 ; 
       }
       Set<Integer> numsSet = new HashSet<>() ; 
       for (int [] row : intervals) {
           for (int k = row[0]; k < row[1]; k++) {
               if (!numsSet.contains(k)) {
                   numsSet.add(k);
               }
           }
       }
    return numsSet.size();
   }
```

since using Sets is generally faster than using Arrays or ArrayLists I think this would make your code faster as you requested.

I know that this is an old answer and you might have found it on your own but it's good to be here for all to see if somebody else encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sumIntervals(int[][] intervals) {
    // TODO: implement this method
    if (intervals == null || intervals.length == 0) return 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int[] start = new int[intervals.length];
    int[] end = new int[intervals.length];
    for (int[] interval : intervals){
        start[counter] = interval[0];
        end[counter] = interval[1];
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= intervals.length - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < intervals.length; j++){
            if (start[j] >= start[i] && start[j] < end[i] && end[j] > end[i])
                start[j] = end[i]; //start of the second interval inside of the first interval 
            if (end[j] >= start[i] && end[j] < end[i] && start[j] < start[i])
                end[j] = start[i]; //end of the second interval inside of the first interval 
            if (start[j] >= start[i] && start[j] < end[i] && end[j] > start[i] && end[j] <= end[i])
                end[j] = start[j]; //whole the second interval inside of the first interval 
            if (start[j] <= start[i] && end[j] >= end[i])
                end[i] = start[i]; //whole the first interval inside of the second interval 
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++)
        counter += end[i] - start[i];
    return counter;
}
```